# Obtaining generating function for multivariate recurrence with non-constant coefficients

Tags: co.combinatorics, differential-equations, recurrences

Consider a second order recurrence of the form below for some fixed $n$

\begin{align}
(n+s-1) A_{n}(k,s) &= (n-k+1) A_{n}(k-1,s-1) + (k+s-3) A_{n}(k,s-1) \\
A_n(k,s) &= 0 \tag{when $s < k$ or $k > n$} \\
A_n(1,s) &= \boldsymbol{1}[s = 1]
\end{align}

I would like to obtain a closed form expression for a generating function of the form

$$G_n(x,y) = \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{s=k}^\infty A_n(k,s) x^k y^s$$

I first observed for non-negative integers $p_x, p_y$ that

\begin{align}
x^{p_x} y^{p_y} G_n(x,y) &= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sum_{s=k}^\infty A_n(k, s) x^{k+p_x} y^{s+p_y} \\
&= \sum_{k=1+p_x}^{n+p_x} \sum_{s=k+p_y}^\infty A_n(k-p_x, s-p_y) x^k y^s
\end{align}

In the same spirit, I noticed the below result , which holds similarly when considering partial derivatives with respect to $y$.
\begin{align}
x \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left\lbrace x^{p_x} y^{p_y} G_n(x,y)\right\rbrace &= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sum_{s=k}^\infty x \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left\lbrace A_n(k, s) x^{k+p_x} y^{s+p_y} \right\rbrace \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sum_{s=k}^\infty (k+p_x) A_n(k, s) x^{k+p_x} y^{s+p_y} \\
&= \sum_{k=1+p_x}^{n+p_x} \sum_{s=k+p_y}^\infty k A_n(k-p_x, s-p_y) x^{k} y^{s}
\end{align}

Using these ideas, I tried to formulate a relationship between the generating function and the given recurrence. In particular, notice the following useful relationships

\begin{align}
(n-1)G_n(x,y) + y \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left\lbrace G_n(x,y)\right\rbrace &= \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{s=k}^\infty (n+s-1)A_n(k,s) x^k y^s \tag{1} \\
(n+1) xyG_n(x,y) - x \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left\lbrace x y G_n(x,y)\right\rbrace &= \sum_{k=2}^{n+1} \sum_{s=k+1}^\infty (n-k+1) A_n(k-1,s-1) x^k y^s \tag{2} \\ 
-3 y G_n(x,y) + x \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left\lbrace y G_n(x,y)\right\rbrace + y \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left\lbrace y G_n(x,y)\right\rbrace &= \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{s=k+1}^\infty (k+s-3) A_n(k,s-1) x^k y^s \tag{3}
\end{align}

If we first simplify the left-hand side when we do $(1) - (2) - (3)$, we can find that

\begin{align}
\text{LHS}\lbrace (1) - (2) - (3) \rbrace &= \left((n - 1) + 3y - (n+1) x y \right) G_n(x,y) + x y \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left\lbrace (x - 1) G_n(x,y)\right\rbrace + y \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left\lbrace (1-y) G_n(x,y)\right\rbrace \\
&= \left((n - 1) + 2y - n x y \right)G_n(x,y) + x y (x-1)\frac{\partial G_n}{\partial x}(x,y) + y (1-y)\frac{\partial G_n}{\partial y}(x,y) \tag{4}
\end{align}

We can do similarly for the right-hand side of $(1) - (2) - (3)$ and find that

\begin{align}
\text{RHS}\lbrace (1) - (2) - (3) \rbrace &= x \left\lbrace\sum_{s=1}^\infty (n+s-1) \underbrace{A_n(1,s)}_{1 \iff s=1} y^s + \sum_{s=2}^\infty (s-2) \underbrace{A_n(1,s)}_{0} y^s\right\rbrace+ (n+1)A_n(2,2)x^2 y^2 \\
& + \sum_{k=2}^{n} \sum_{s=k+1}^\infty \underbrace{\left((n+s-1) A_{n}(k,s) - (n-k+1) A_{n}(k-1,s-1) - (k+s-3) A_{n}(k,s-1)\right)}_{0} \\
&= n x y + (n+1) A_n(2,2) x^2 y^2 \tag{5}
\end{align}

where we can use the recurrence to find that $A_n(2,2) = \frac{(n-1)}{(n+1)}$. Putting $(4)$ and $(5)$ together, we find that the generating function must satisfy the following first order linear partial differential equation:

$$\left((n - 1) + 2y - n x y \right) G_n(x,y) + x y (x-1)\frac{\partial G_n}{\partial x}(x,y) + y (1-y)\frac{\partial G_n}{\partial y}(x,y) = n x y + (n-1) x^2 y^2$$

From here, I am not certain about a few things. I am not well enough versed in using generating functions to solve multivariate recurrences with non-constant coefficients. A big question is, what boundary conditions should I be using for this partial differential equation? Given I have some boundary conditions, I am aware that the above equation can be approached using the method of characteristics, but I feel this is a bit complicated (assuming no errors).

Does anyone have any advice on whether this is the right way to work out the generating function $G_n(x,y)$? Is there a better alternative?

Comment: Typically boundary conditions from the recurrence initial conditions. E.g., in your case we have $\frac{\partial G_n}{\partial x}(0,y) = y$.